# How do redraw the swt composite after clicking a button to change the content of that composite

Tags: java, swt

I am new to SWT. The project I am working on has a main composite with 3 children composite on it. the Upper composite consist with buttons, and the middle composite is for displaying content, and the lower composite is for other purpose. What has to happen is when i click a button in the upper composite, it has to trigger the content change in the middle composite. 
this is the code i am used to do this

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    /* Retrieve the contents that are currently in middle composite*/
    Composite currentCenterComposite = EMWindow.getCenterCompsiteState();
    /* Retrieve the main composite*/
    Composite outerComposite=EMWindow.getOuterCompsiteState();
    if ((currentCenterComposite != null) && (!currentCenterComposite.isDisposed())) {
    /* Remove children that are already laid out */
    Object[] children = currentCenterComposite.getChildren (); 
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
 ((Composite)children[i]).dispose();
     }
    }

    currentCenterComposite = new CenterComp(currentCenterComposite);
    GridData gd_centerComposite = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
    gd_centerComposite.minimumHeight = 50;
    currentCenterComposite.setLayoutData(gd_centerComposite);
    currentCenterComposite.layout(true);
    //currentOuterComposite.layout();
    outerComposite.layout(true);
}
```

The Problem right now is after i click the button and above code was executed, nothing seems happen until i resize the GUI, then the content in the middle composite will appear.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. I have composite which has some text fields and buttons. I want to add a new checkbox field on click of a button. It is getting added but I can see only on resizing the UI.
I tried calling layout on Composite..but that is not doing anything...Can you let me know how did you fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Composite.layout() = "If the receiver has a **layout**, asks the layout to *lay out*"

Note that Layout and LayoutData are two different things. The LayoutData tells the Composite how to behave on the parent. The Layout tells the Composite how to arrange its children. In your case, you are NOT setting a layout on currentCenterComposite, therefor calling layout() has no effect.

Try to also set a Layout on your composite.